# Programmatically minimize all windows or besides my Cocoa application?

Tags: swift, cocoa, window, nswindow, minimize

I haven't been able to find anything about this in Swift. Is there a way to programmatically make my application minimize all other windows open in the background, or even just minimize Safari? I basically want my application to run against the desktop, without any clutter in the background. Is there a way to programmatically do this for a Cocoa app? I'm pretty new to swift, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use api on `NSWorkspace` which allows you to hide all visible app in the background.
You can find more about `NSWorkspace` here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html)

Hides all applications other than the sender. This method must be called from your app’s main thread.

```
NSWorkspace.shared().hideOtherApplications()
```

If you only want to hide Safari,

```
  let appPath = NSWorkspace.shared().fullPath(forApplication: "Safari")
  let identifier = Bundle.init(path: appPath!)?.bundleIdentifier

  if let bundleID = identifier {
  let runningApps = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier:bundleID )
        if !runningApps.isEmpty {
            runningApps.first?.hide()
        }
    }
```